# databricks notebook link to github 404 Not Found error

Tags: azure, github, databricks, azure-databricks

In order to link Databricks notebook to github, I have followed this instruction: https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/github-version-control.html

Previously it worked for me, but now after changing to a new Azure environment, it kept showing me "404 Not Found" error like this:

[image]

The github path and folder I have definied were all correct. Permission for github personal key is also correct.
Also weird, think notebook can link to the old github repo I have created before, but can't link to any new github repo...

Do you know anything else I can try in order to link correctly?

Comment: Can you try to use Repos functionality instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos ?

Comment: @AlexOtt great, now I can save the files into Github. Thank you very much! BTW, do you know is that possible to save notebook in `.ipynb` format? With this method, notebooks will be saved as .py automatically

Comment: Not yet, right now it saves data as just source code. One of the reasons - to prevent committing of output by mistake - it could contain sensitive data